# Issue with ROC curve where 'test positive' is below a certain threshold

Tags: r, roc, diagnostics, medical

I am working on evaluating a screening test for osteoporosis, and I have a large set of data where we measured values of bone density. We classified individuals as being 'disease positive' for osteoporosis if they had a vertebral fracture present on the images when we took the bone density measure.

The 'disease positive' has a lower distribution of the continuous value than the disease negative group.

We want to determine which threshold for the continuous variable is best for determining if an individual is at a higher risk for future fractures.  We've found that the lower the value is, the higher the risk.  I used Stata to create some tables to calculate sensitivity and specificity at a few different thresholds.  Again, a person is 'test positive' if their value is *below* the threshold.  [I made this table here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvrdZ.png)

We wanted to show this in graphical form, so I decided to make an ROC curve, and I used the ROCR package to do so.  Here is the code I used in R:

```
library(ROCR)
prevalentfx <- read.csv("prevalentfxnew.csv", header = TRUE)    

pred <- prediction(prevalentfx$l1_hu, prevalentfx$fx)
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")

plot(perf, print.cutoffs.at = c(50,90,110,120), points.pch = 20, points.col = "darkblue", 
         text.adj=c(1.2,-0.5))
```

And here is what comes out:
[Not what I expected!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhXCo.jpg)

This didn't make sense to me because according to the few thresholds where I calculated sensitivity and specificity manually (in the table), 50 HU is the *least* sensitive threshold and 120 is the *most* sensitive.  Additionally, I feel like the curve is flipped along the diagonal axis.  I know that this test is not *that* poor.

I figured this issue was due to the fact that a person is 'test positive' if the value is *below* the threshold, not above them. So, I just created a new vector of values where I flipped the binary classification and re-created the ROC plot, and got a figure which aligns much better with the data. However, the threshold values are still opposite of what they should be.

Is there something fundamentally wrong with how I'm looking at this?  I have double checked our data several times to make sure I wasn't miscalculating the sensitivity and specificity values, and it all looks right.  Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is a working example:

```
library(ROCR)

low <- rnorm(200, mean = 73, sd = 42)
high<- rnorm(3000, mean = 133, sd = 51.5)

measure <- c(low, high)
df = data.frame(measure)

df$fx <- rep.int(1, 200)
df$fx[201:3200] <- rep.int(0,3000)

pred <- prediction(df$measure, df$fx)
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")

plot(perf,print.cutoffs.at=c(50,90,110,120), points.pch = 20, points.col = "darkblue", 
     text.adj=c(1.2,-0.5))
```

Comment: please provide a reproducible example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you could just `dput()` the data, that would be great. For the R tag our rule (per the tag description) is *"Please supplement your question with a minimal reproducible example. Use `dput()` for data and specify all non-base packages with library calls."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution (although inelegant) might be to use the negative values (rather than reversing your classification):

```
pred <- prediction(-df$measure, df$fx)
perf <- performance(pred, "tpr", "fpr")
plot(perf, 
     print.cutoffs.at=-c(50,90,110,120), 
     cutoff.label.function=`-`,
     points.pch = 20, points.col = "darkblue", 
     text.adj=c(1.2,-0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I used this, and ended up just photo-editing the negative signs out of the final figure.  I may contact the author of the ROCR package as well to see if he has a different solution which wouldn't require this last step.

Comment: I just noticed that the `plot` method for the `performance` object has a `cutoff.label.function` argument that allows you to apply any function to the cutoff labels.  In this case, `-` would do the trick, so you shouldn't have to do post-processing of the plot.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Weihuang Wong is correct for ROC curves. However, if you want TPR vs Cutoff per your convention, this does not work. In that case, invert the measure instead of negating the cutoff: plot FNR vs Cutoff and relabel the axis to "TPR". (FNR=1-TPR).