# Set the number of thresholds for ROC curve R ROCR

Tags: r, roc

I am using the roc.curve of the ROCR package which provides a beautiful plot that is colorized according to the used threshold

using this code

```
library(ROCR)
pred <- prediction(predicted, response)
perf <- performance( pred, "tpr", "fpr" )
plot( perf, colorize = TRUE)
```

[image]

This function plots the ROC curve automatically, and even if it tries to fit in other to find good threshold values, but I have no control over how many thresholds are used or the range of the thresholds picked.

I have found another roc.curve function from another package called ROSE find more here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ROSE/versions/0.0-4/topics/roc.curve

In this function I have the possibility to set a number of thresholds

```
library(ROSE)
roc.curve(response, predicted, plotit = TRUE, add.roc = FALSE, n.thresholds=100)
```

[image]

I was wondering if there is a similar option for the function in ROCR package.
Thank you
PS I was wondering too why my roc curves are not similar, as if the TPR(true positif rate) and FPR(false positif rate) have been inverted

Comment: PS you should ask this part in a separate question. Please limit a question to one question.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make another post. But do you have any idea why the two curves seem to be inverted?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### You can't!

By definition, a ROC curve goes over ***all thresholds***.

### And shouldn't.

If you limit the number of thresholds you use, like the ROSE package seems to do, this is no longer a ROC curve.

The curve given by ROCR already contains all thresholds between -Inf and +Inf. There is no way you can add more thresholds to it.

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: And the reason you are seeing the inversion of your ROC curve is probably that you want the cutoff to work in the opposite direction. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441280/issue-with-roc-curve-where-test-positive-is-below-a-certain-threshold